# What is the fastest way to print from an ePrint printer?

Tags: network-printer

My office has an ePrint printer but I don't know how to print from it. Currently our staffs print by using a shared printer from a specific PC. The owner of this PC has installed the driver using CD drive (which is nothing related to ePrint at all)

If you know how to use ePrint printer, please share!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to use ePrint, you should follow these steps:

1. Add your staff's emails which are allowed to use ePrint printer on ePrinCenter.com.
2. Then, you must to provide Printer's email to your staff
3. To print a document by ePrint Printer, it's very simple, your staff only need to send an email to Printer, don't forget to add the file which he wants to print.

That's all.